# Video upload - List data Validation failed

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, validation

I tried uploading two files ("sample video 1" and "Gitte godsk"), both of them have the same features, details and both of them are mp4 format.
"Sample Video 1" uploads successfully.
For "Gitte godsk" I get this error "List data validation failed.
What could be reason behind this?
[image]

Comment: Is there any column or list/library validation applied?

Comment: Please go to List settings -> Validation Settings to check whether there is validation in it?

Comment: No. Formulas are empty. Nothing is added